# Remove user from usergroup independent of language settings

Tags: powershell

I want to remove member "RAdmin" from "Users" group and the below code works. Problem is if the language settings on system is in another language than english it does not work, for example if it is "Benutzer" (German) or "Usuarios" (Spanish). Please let me know how to handle this issue.

```
$members = "RAdmin"
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users" -Member $members
```

I tried like below

```
$members = "RAdmin"
$groupsToRemoveFrom = @("Usuarios", "Users", "Benutzer")

foreach ($group in $groupsToRemoveFrom) {
    if (Test-Path "LocalGroup:\$group") {
        $result = Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group $group -Member $members -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($result) {
            # Removal was successful
            Write-Host "Removed $($members) from '$($group)'"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Built-in groups like 'Users' have [Well-known SIDs](https://morgantechspace.com/2013/10/well-known-sids-and-built-in-groups.html) see also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers#well-known-sids), so you could do 
`Remove-LocalGroupMember -SID 'S-1-5-32-545' -Member $members`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in groups may have localized names, but common groups like `Users` have [Well-known SIDs](https://morgantechspace.com/2013/10/well-known-sids-and-built-in-groups.html) you can use to identify them, regardless of the language installed.

In your case you will need sid `S-1-5-32-545`, so instead of using the localized name you can do

```
Remove-LocalGroupMember -SID 'S-1-5-32-545' -Member $members
```